# Java - What is the explanation of this code?

Tags: java, image

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width1; j++) {
    int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(i, j);
    int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(i, j);
    int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g1 = (rgb1 >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b1 = (rgb1      ) & 0xff;
    int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g2 = (rgb2 >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b2 = (rgb2      ) & 0xff;
    diff += Math.abs(r1 - r2);
    diff += Math.abs(g1 - g2);
    diff += Math.abs(b1 - b2);
  }
}
double n = width1 * height1 * 3;
double p = diff / n / 255.0;
System.out.println("diff percent: " + (p * 100.0));
```

The code is used to find the percentage of difference between images, but i don’t know why the percentage is divided by “n” and by “255.0”

Thanks

Comment: This is more about Maths. You have n pixels and each can change up to 255. So now you want to convert this in a number between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pixel consists of 3 color components:

- R - the red color component
- G - the green color component
- B - the blue color component

Each of these color components is represented as a single byte - that is, with 8 bits. The maximum value that can be represented with a byte is 255.

So in order to compute the difference in percent, you compute the sum of differences of all color components of all pixels, and divide this sum...

- by the number of pixels, to obtain the average difference per pixel
- by 3, to obtain the average difference per color component
- by 255, to obtain a value between 0.0 and 1.0 which can be converted into a percent value

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself, what would happend if it did not ?
It only depends on the unit of the percent, percent of what ? Units of RGB per pixel ?
Concerning the 255, there is one byte for each color: so 8 bits, 2 power of 8 is 256 means 0 to 255=256 possibilities per color component.

Answer (score 0):

n times 255 is the maximum difference possible. That is if all colors had a difference of 255. diff is the actual difference. To get percentage you have to divide actual with total and multiply with 100.0

By the way the following is true:

```
diff / n / 255 = diff / (n * 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

It serves normalization purposes for the 24-bit color depth and the size of the picture. The iteration in the loop will run exactly n/3 times, and inside each iteration diff will be increased with 3 numbers in the range [0-255].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like diff variable holds sum of all colors (red + green + blue) difference of all pixels (width * height) of the image.

So:

```
double n = width1 * height1 * 3;
```

holds information how many times you added differences of colors of every pixel to diff.
Color value is between 0 and 255 for RGB.

p variable range is between 0 and 1, so you have to divide diff by n and 255.

Then on output you just multiply p by 100 to get percentage.